# fgets read stdin endlessly again when i run background in my customshell

Tags: c, shell, unix, background-process

```c
int bg = 0;
void myhandler(int num) {
  printf("handler work\n");
  waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  pid_t pid;

  struct sigaction act;
  act.sa_flags = 0;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_handler = myhandler;
  sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0);
while (1) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fgets(cmdline, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    cmdline[strlen(cmdline) - 1] = '\0';
    //check background
    if (cmdline[strlen(cmdline) - 1] == '&') {
      bg = 1;
      cmdline[strlen(cmdline) - 1] = '\0';
    }
      switch (pid = fork()) {
      case 0:
       makelist(cmdline, " \t", cmdvector, MAX_CMD_ARG);
        printf("child\n");
        execvp(cmdvector[0], cmdvector);
        fatal("main()");
        return 0;
      case -1:
        fatal("main()");
      default:
        if (bg) {
          waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
        } else {
          wait(NULL);
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

hi i am making custom shell and i encounter problem can't figure out.
when i input

> sleep 1

it works well
but if i want background

> sleep 1 &

infinite loop comes out.
fgets() function read first input by stdin. why it does? only for background process
if i set

> sa_flags = SA_RESTART

it works well again
what's wrong with code?

Comment: `&` character will never be at `cmdline[strlen(cmdline) - 1]`: in fact the last character of `cmdline` will always be `'\n'` that is preserved by `fgets()`. This means that `myCommand &` is executed instead of `myCommand`.

Comment: i think that's not related to this problem and removing '&' needs to run command